# Why is the moment of inertia of a rod not the same as that of a disk?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Take a disk and cut it to the centre like you'd do with scissors, and bring the cut sides to each other taking along all the mass in the middle. you'd have a rod. This should work because $R$ for the individual particles don't change when you're squeezing (moment of inertia of two particles of mass m on opposite sides of diameter of a circle is $2m R^2$, like one particle of mass $2m$).

This works for a ring and a point mass, why not for a disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is flawed in one important way:

When you cut the disc to the centre and collapse it like closing a fan, the "rod" created is ***not*** uniform, in terms of mass distribution, along its length.

The part of the rod close to the centre of the disc contains the mass on a short circular line from the former disc.  The other end of the rod contains more mass formerly on a much larger circle.

Comment: oh that's right, but then why is the MI of a disk the same as half a disk, quarter disk, 1/8th disk etc?

Comment: Assuming that the fractional discs are all pie-shaped pieces of various sizes, the distribution of mass radially outward is the same for all pieces, irrespective of size...

Comment: uh, hey, another question if you don't mind - I can use the same logic for a sharply bent rod (at centre) and say the MI (in location of bent perpendicular to plane of rod)  same regardless of the angle of bent. I can keep making this angle smaller and then suddenly it poofs and the moment of inertia changes?

Comment: There is no change in the moment of inertia in the situation described...

Comment: won't i get a single straight rod when the angle bw the rods is 0? that'll be mr^2/3 as opposed to mr^2/12 right?

Comment: These two different formulae have different definitions of r...